# Is there any algorithm or source code available for indentation available?

Tags: java

I need to know the algorithm or source code for the indentations used in java IDE (Eclipse)

Answer (score 5):

You can find the source code as part of the JDT. It's not easy to find, though. [This git repo should have what you need](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/). Search for "clone" on the page to see how to clone it.

Here are the [sources of the public API](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.core/formatter/org/eclipse/jdt/core/formatter). The actual [implementation is here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.core/formatter/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/formatter).

Comment: Thanks Aaron...would be looking out for it!

Answer (score 2):

The Eclipse IDE is open source, so you should be able to download and read the source code for the precise algorithms that Eclipse uses.